# Change Bootstrap Active nav-pills tab border bottom shape to solid underline

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to change the Bootstrap Active Tab of nav-pills border bottom to rectangle. The end points are curved and unable to change it to be a solid underline.

Refer this Link: Bootstrap Nav Pills - JSFiddle - I dont know how to put jsfiddle link here. anwyasys. below is the code. kindly help out. jquery above 2.X version use. Unable to resolve the jsfiddle.net link insertion properly

```
 $(document).ready(function () {console.log("highlight.js file executed...");
     $('ul.nav > li > a').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); $('.initial-active').removeClass('initial-active');
         $('ul.nav > li > a').removeClass('active');
         $(this).addClass('active'); 
    });
 });

<h2 class="text-center">Bootstrap Navpills </h2><br /><ul class="nav nav-pills text-center nav-justified ulthis"> 
    <li class="initial-active" role="apisolution">
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#pricequoteapi">
            <img alt="Price Quote API" src="http://browseideas.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/random-mood-photography-20-575x378.png" width="70" height="81" /> <br /> 
            <div>PQ</div> 
        </a> 
    </li> 
    <li role="apisolution"> 
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#claimadjustapi">
            <img alt="Claim Adjust API" src="https://img00.deviantart.net/08d8/i/2011/040/4/7/random_photography____by_doineedtoknow-d396v4j.jpg" width="70" height="81" /> <br /> 
            <div>CA</div>
        </a> 
    </li> 
    <li role="apisolution"> 
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#druglistapi">
            <img alt="Drug List API" src="http://www.samhorine.com/imagesrandom/random8.jpg" width="70" height="81" /> <br /> 
            <div>DL</div> 
        </a> 
    </li> 
    <li role="apisolution"> 
         <a data-toggle="pill" href="#medpricingapi">
             <img alt="Med Pricing API" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3864/14258413420_5717547046_z.jpg" width="70" height="81" /> <br />
        <div>MP</div>
        </a> 
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="pricequoteapi"> 
    <div> 
     <h3>PQ</h3>  
       <p>PQ section.</p> 
    </div>
   </div>
     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="claimadjustapi"> 
         <div> <h3>CA</h3> 
              <p>CA section</p> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="druglistapi"> <div> <h3>DL</h3> 
    <p>DL section</p> </div> </div> <div class="tab-pane fade" id="medpricingapi"> <div> 
      <h3>MP</h3> <p>MP section</p> </div> </div></div>
    .nav-pills>li.active>a,.nav-pills>li.active>a:focus,.nav-pills>li.active>a:hover{ color:black; background-color:white;}.initial-active{ border-bottom: 10px solid #5bc0eb;}.nav > li > a.active { border-bottom: 10px solid #5bc0eb;}.ulthis { border-bottom: 2px solid #FF5FFF;}
```

Images: Expected One - Active Nav Pills tab being solid underlined [image: expected]

This is the one I am trying to resolve. Observe the rounder edges of the active nav pill. Want to change it to like Expected One above [image: unexpected]

Please refer the code in the JSFiddle link above. Kindly help out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.nav > li > a.active { border-bottom: 10px solid #5bc0eb; border-radius: none}
```

Looks like it might have a border-radius predefined, with this it gets reset to 0 radius.

Comment: I figured it out before few minutes. but thank you for helping out! this resolved my issue :)

Comment: @Vivek22 Glad if I could help.