# Drupal 8 jQuery 3.3.1 Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ul.nav &gt; li &gt; a error while applying the javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drupal-8, jquery-3

Newbee here.

(plz refer this link: [Change Bootstrap Active nav-pills tab border bottom shape to solid underline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069404/change-bootstrap-active-nav-pills-tab-border-bottom-shape-to-solid-underline)
 - i was trying to achieve this one)

I tried to apply the js file for underlining the active tab of bootstrap nav pills. While the custom js file based out on default jquery in drupal 8 is loaded, getting the following error

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ul.nav &gt; li &gt; a  jquery-3.3.1.js:1541:8
Sizzle</Sizzle.error https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:1541:8
Sizzle</Sizzle.tokenize https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:2193:4
Sizzle</Sizzle.select https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:2620:20
Sizzle https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:845:9
.find https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:2873:4
jQuery.fn.init https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:2983:14
jQuery https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:139:10
<anonymous> http://localhost:8080/developer-portal/htdocs/:1116:37
resolve/</mightThrow https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:3534:21
resolve/</process< https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:3602:12
```

Kindly help out how to resolve this error.

enclosed in double quotes too as per mentioned here [child selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/). But didnt help.

custom jquery used:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { console.log("highlight.js file executed... ggfh"); jQuery('ul.nav > li > a').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); jQuery('.initial-active').removeClass('initial-active'); jQuery('ul.nav > li > a').removeClass('active'); jQuery(this).addClass('active'); }); });
```

mentioned properly in info.yml and libraries.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal escapes your js code (`>` => `&gt;`).

Your can put you js code in a js file, and using `<script>` tag imports you code.